# Where is my mistake in a logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

Prove that

$$3^{\log_2 5} = 5^{\log_2 3}$$

is true.

Here is my solution:

[image]

Comment: Typesetting your solution in MathJax to add to your question would greatly improve its quality. No one likes squinting at pictures! There is a brief tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Why do you multiply the two expressions. It should be $3^{\log_2 5} -5^{\log_2 3}=0$ OR $3^{\log_2 5} \cdot 5^{-\log_2 3}=1$

Comment: Well I divide the one side by the other.

Comment: Then the RHS has to be 1.

Comment: Oh yeah - OMG you genius. Saved my life bro.

Comment: So then my solution must be ok? Excluding that RHS has to be 0.

Comment: Yes, it´s looking O.K. $3^0=1$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is just to take $\log_2$ of both sides.

---

In the picture I see an expression which looks like $3^X=0$. But there isn't a real number $X$ for which this is true. You would need the expression to be equal to $1$ for the exponent to be zero.

Comment: How to do this? Please explain, also if you look at my solution I'll be grateful too.

Comment: @FISOCPP  $\log_c a^b=b\log_c a$ is a basic proprty of logarithms to any base.

Comment: Please write this down if possible.

Comment: @FISOCPP RowanS's answer writes it down.

Answer (score 2):

$$ 3^{\log(5)}=5^{\log(3)} \iff\log(3^{\log(5)})=\log(5^{\log(3)}) \iff \log(3)\log(5)=\log(3)\log(5)$$